# Selectpicker is not working when I try to display JSON data using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

When I write $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); in the console it is loading.. Where should I provide this code?

My HTML code is

```
 <form action="" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="categories">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Your City" v-model="category" name="category">
            <option v-for="post in articles" v-bind:value="post.name">{{post.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory">
            <option v-for="so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My vue js script is as given below.. I have added the script in the mount() but nothing happens for me. But when I type in the console.. drop down list appears

```
  <script>
categories = new Vue({
    el: '#categories',
    data: {
        articles: [],
        services: [],
        category: 0,
        subcategory: 0,
        content: false
    },
      watch: {
           subcategory: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
           category: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.subcategory = 0;
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
              data: {
                'service': self.id
              },
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(e) {
              console.log('Loading services');
              console.log(self.category);
              let categoryIdArray = self.articles.filter(x=>x.name==self.category);
                console.log(categoryIdArray);
                self.services = e.filter(x=>x.cat_id==categoryIdArray[0].cat_id);
                 console.log(self.services);
                self.prefetch();

              }
            });
          },
      },

    mounted: function() {

   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

        var vm = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {

                    console.log(e); 
                 vm.articles = e;
                console.log(vm);
            },
        });
    },

})
</script>
```

Is there any way to initialize select picker? Please help me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160000/discussion-on-question-by-med-selectpicker-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-display).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
});
```

Comment: i am able to load category by this.. but i am not able to load subcategory

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Ok, now I understand what you want to do... You want to use the [boostrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin and Vue.

First of all your dependencies are wrong, the plugin doesn't have compatibility with newer version of jQuery and Bootstrap, I used exactly the same versions that are in the example page of the plugin.

Secondly, Vue is updating the values of the options after that the plugin rendered the select so you don't see the dropdown. The correct way should be to import the plugin after the ajax calls, but for your case you should re-render the plugin when the calls return. If you call the refresh method in the mounted, again the render is done too early. To workaround this you can put the refresh inside a timeout to put it at the end of the digest cycle. [Check this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnn9kz39/8/).

**This is only a workaround, you should work on the import and correctly update the plugin.**

---

To preload values in the `selectPicker` you must initialize the values of `vm.category` and `vm.subcategory`. You can do this in the `mounted()` method.

Here's an example (I used [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to speed up the coding):

```
async mounted() {
  var vm = this;

  //First thing GET all the articles
  vm.articles = await $.ajax({
    url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON"
  });

  //Select the first result as your category (you should check if there are articles)
  vm.category = vm.articles[0].cat_id

  //Here you get the services... really strange WS since it returns all the services, not filtered by category...
  vm.allServices = await $.ajax({
    url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
    data: {
      'service': vm.category //????
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON"
  })
  //... so we have to filter them in the client!
  vm.services = vm.allServices.filter(s => s.cat_id === vm.category);

  //Now select the subcategory to preload it
  vm.subcategory = vm.services[0].sub_cat_id;
  //You can call the fetch WS to get the content with category and subcategory
  this.prefetch();
}
```

You should also change you view and set the `v-bind:value=` to `post.cat_id` and `so.sub_cat_id`.

[Here is a jfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gnn9kz39/6/)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub_cat_id' of undefined

Comment: The fiddle for me is working... Try to understand the error: where do you use `sub_cat_id`? What can be `undefined`? HINT: `vm.services[0].sub_cat_id;`, does it mean that `vm.services[0]` is `undefined`? Why? What can you do to solve/check it?