# Vue Js: selectpicker(''refresh") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, vue.js, vue-component

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
```

This is done to initialize the selectpicker. When I run this is in console of chrome.. the dropdown list appears. So, in vuejs I added this code in mount(). But nothing is happening.. I have asked another question regarding the same and did not got an answer. Is there any way to initialize the same. My front end is html and vuejs and backend in python Django.. I am stuck or last two days and did not get anything new. Is there any way to initialize the same?

My html code is

```
<form action="" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="categories">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Your City" v-model="category" name="category">
            <option v-for="post in articles" v-bind:value="post.name">{{post.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory">
            <option v-for="so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My vue js code is

```
 <script>
searchContent = new Vue({
        el: "#searchContent",
        data: {
          vector: {}
        }
      });
categories = new Vue({
    el: '#categories',
    data: {
        articles: [],
        services: [],
        category: 0,
        subcategory: 0,
        businessName: 0,
        district: 0,
        content: false
    },
      watch: {
           subcategory: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
          businessName: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
          district: function(e) {
            this.prefetch();
          },
           category: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.subcategory = 0;
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_services/",
              data: {
                'service': self.id
              },
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(e) {
              console.log('Loading services');
              console.log(self.category);
              let categoryIdArray = self.articles.filter(x=>x.name==self.category);
                console.log(categoryIdArray);
                self.services = e.filter(x=>x.cat_id==categoryIdArray[0].cat_id);
                 console.log(self.services);
                self.prefetch();

              }
            });
          },
      },
    mounted: function() {



        var vm = this;
this.$nextTick(function () {
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
  });
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {

                    console.log(e); 
                 vm.articles = e;
                console.log(vm);
            },
        });
    },

          methods: {
          prefetch: function() {
            var filter = {};
            filter['category'] = this.category;
            filter['subcategory'] = this.subcategory;
            filter['businessName'] = this.businessName;
             filter['district'] = this.district;
            if (this.content !== false)
              this.content.abort()
            this.content = $.ajax({
              'url': 'https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/filter/',
              data: filter,
              dataType: "JSON",
              type: "POST",
              success: function(e) {

                 window.searchContent.vector = e.data;
                console.log(e);
              }
            })
          }
        }

})
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: @ankitapatel  iUpdated

Comment: What about the consoles? are they getting printed in the correct order?

Comment: yes sir.. everthing is working fine.. If I remove class="selectpicker" from html code, everything is coming rightly

Comment: So if the selectpicker code is still there, does it affect the consoles? If yes how does it change?

Comment: sir by using class="selectpicker".. if I provide 
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') in the chrome console.. dropdown list is coming..

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console when you select refresh code? maybe try this outside all your vue components?

Comment: there is no errors in the console, sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selectpicker is not working when I try to display JSON data using vue js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527294/selectpicker-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-display-json-data-using-vue-js)

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vue 2, you might need to use `nextTick` in mounted hook.

According to Vue.js document:

> Note that `mounted` does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use `vm.$nextTick` inside of `mounted`:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping.. but tried.. but still same effect

Comment: this.$nextTick(function () {
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                    alert("ogbfds")
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')  }); SIR If I add a alert category is loading.. but sucategory is not still loading

Comment: Seems that `$('.selectpicker')` is not getting the correct elements. You may solve it with a `setTimeout` call, but that's not a safe way.

Comment: is there any way to initialize the same

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527294/selectpicker-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-display-json-data-using-vue-js/47536584#47536584)? I also suggested to use setTimeout, but as @wxsm said it is not the best practice...

Comment: I need a solution

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem where `select` inputs were modified by `vue.js` and thus they were conflicting. For me the `solution` was this:

```js
updated() {
    $('.bSelect').selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true,
        size: 10
    });
    $('.bSelect').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```